# What are the standard Microsoft Office margins for double-sided printing on A4?

Tags: microsoft-office, margins, standards

I am asking because I am supposed to use standard Microsoft Word margins and the document is going to be printed double-sided. I want to figure out what those margins would be in Microsoft Word and then try to replicate them in LaTeX because I am going to write my document in this language. I guess the `geometry` package would suffice for that.

Note some comments under this question might not make sense because this has question migrated from http://tex.stackexchange.com and has been significantly edited.

Comment: I afraid your question is off-topic here, I think you should ask on Super User.

Comment: AFAICT, the only relationship your query has to "a WYSIWYG text editor like Microsoft Word, LibreOffice or OpenOffice" is that you are "supposed to use standard Microsoft Word margins". And what would those margins be? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico that's what I want to establish. I want to know what are standard double-printing margins in e.g. Microsoft Word so that I can try to somehow replicate it in LaTeX.

Comment: There are no "fixed" margins for DOC ODT DOCX  files as it is paper / printer / template driven narrow might be 15 mm in one language or 1/2" in another take your pick and throw points at it by default there is no offset one side or the other both sides the same to start

Comment: @geras - Your objective is currently so vague as to be unanswerable. E.g., the answer must surely depend on the overall page size (A4?, US Letter?, something else?), about which you've been rather silent. National typographic conventions will likely playa role as well, but you're not exactly telling us a lot about any such conventions you must satisfy.

Comment: @Mico A4, sorry, I forgot to specify.

Comment: I suppose my question is just: "What are the standard margins for double-sided printing in Microsoft Word on A4 paper"?

Comment: Maybe also "and how can replicate this in LaTeX?" but I could probably figure it out using the `geometry` package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a LaTeX document appear as though it were typeset in MS Word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39544/making-a-latex-document-appear-as-though-it-were-typeset-in-ms-word)

Comment: @CarLaTeX OK, I will ask on SuperUser. I just need to wait 40 minutes before I ask another question.

Comment: I suggest you load the your document class with the options `twoside` and `a4paper` and issue the instruction `\usepackage[vmargin=1in, outer=1.25in, inner=1in]{geometry}`, or, more simply, `\usepackage[margin=1in, bindingoffset=0.25in]{geometry}`.

Comment: The question is Whatever the recipient has defined New Out Of Box side margins are 1 1/4 inches roughly 32 mm with top and bottom  1" then I set the side margins to 2cm to maximise the line width and minimise the mechanical gripper top and bottom ALL my margins are set paired why do I need to have different on each side, If I was binding I would look at grippers say double one side to 40mm or drag it  by eye There is no rule

Comment: @geras, double-sides printing is irrelevant to the question.  That just affects how many sheets of paper you use.  There isn't a "standard" for MS Word margins.  Some values need to be specified so Word knows what to work with.  Out of the box, Microsoft picks some somewhat arbitrary values for its default templates.  These are just values that are a reasonable starting point and similar to what people are used to seeing.  But if there are actual requirements, they are typically defined in some kind of style reference that the document is supposed to follow.

Comment: Thanks @fixer1234 , I think you're right with the exception that double-sided printing is relevant to this question because it is supposed to change the layout to allow an offset for binding, like the option `twoside` in LaTeX.

Comment: In Word, allowances for binding are completely separate because they vary by the nature of the binding.  If you staple the corner of the document, there usually isn't any change in margins.  If it is bound along the side or top edge, that margin may be expanded, and could affect odd and even pages differently.  If it is a booklet and bound in the middle, the allowances are different.  Word has a separate set of settings for the binding allowance, and you need to know how it will be bound to make the right selections.  But that is added to the page margin, so the page margin isn't affected.

Comment: For that matter, it may not be bound at all.

Comment: [See also this question on the newer Graphic Design stack](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/134957/how-many-inches-mm-is-left-as-margin-on-a-standard-a4-paper).

Answer (score 1):

The standard margins for Word, for A4 pages are 2.5 cm for each side.

[image: Proof]

Comment: Are you sure? I thought it's 1 inch which is very similar but not the same.

Comment: @geras I had added proof in the answer. The interface is in Romanian.

Comment: Having 2.5 cm for you as default doesn't mean it's 2.5 cm in all regions.

Comment: No. Technically, everybody can make their own standards, regardless of regions.

Comment: @BogdanDoicin, your answer won't work in the US because we have no idea what cm is.  :-)  (only kidding)

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to change over time or regions but for all the people looking at this from the US or in settings where they'll be sending things to the US, the current version of Word defaults to 
**1 inch** (~25.4 mm) **top and bottom margins** and
**1¼ inch** (~31.75 mm) **right and left margins**.
You can change that setting in Layout > Margins.

[image: normal margins for US editions of recent MS Word]

In business settings where it might cost time, money, and/or jobs if whatever you send disappears because of setting disagreements, the normal kludge is to **export the file in .pdf format**, send that, and assume they're bright enough to remember to print with Shrink to Fit, Shrink Oversize Pages, &c. You can also try sending unimportant documents first, seeing what happens to them, and adjusting as necessary.